# Version of double-slit experimen: Was it done? What are results?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

My motivation is role of consciousness in quantum measurement.

Imagine I perform double-slit experiment with a device recording on a paper which slit did photon go through (so there is some detector in each slit). Then without looking on the photograph (where photons landed) and without looking on the paper I burn the paper so the information about path is completely discarded. Only after I look on the photograph. What will I see?

My guess is I will see two spots, yet I am wandering what are experimental results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar experiments have been done many times and the result is as you say, the photon passes through only one slit. In this context the "observer" is typically some form of measuring apparatus, in effect if not in name.

The point of wave collapse is the point at which you *could have* peeked at the path had you wanted to. Whether you did or not turns out to be irrelevant.

But if an experiment is arranged so that you cannot peek even if you wanted to, not even in principle, then you will see a wave diffraction pattern build up.

Comment: It is not so clear to me. If, instead of paper, I will keep the information about path in the entangled-photon partner (eraser experiment) which (the entangled photon) might be hold in a perfect-mirror box, then when I destroy the box (together with the partner photon) I will see interference. What makes such a big difference between "paper" and "mirror box with entangled photon inside"?

Comment: The precise boundaries of such differences are still being explored, but as a working approach we can say that mirrors do not exchange energy with the photon but a detector does. Has the experiment destroying the mirror box been carried out? Does the time order of photon detection vs. destruction make a difference?

Comment: Well, it has been carried out in some sense. Eraser experiments are exactly about this.

Answer (score 0):

Detecting a photon requires that the detector absorbs all of the photon's energy.  If you are working with a single photon and you detect it at a slit, then nothing will arrive at the film beyond the slit. If a single photon passes through one (or more) slits, it can be detected at only one point beyond the slits. The electromagnetic wave associated with a photon passes through your slits and produces an interference pattern on any surface beyond the slits.  At each point in the pattern, the field strength determines the probability that the the photon will be absorbed at that point.